# Did Polaroid's patents on integral photography describe a different technology than what Polaroid used?

Tags: history, polaroid, kodak

I had a colleague at Polaroid in the 1980s who told me that the patents Kodak was accused of violating did not describe the system that Polaroid was actually using in its SX-70 and Spectra film, but instead described a chemistry that Polaroid had decided not to use. Polaroid kept the better system as a trade secret.

I've looked through coverage of the Polaroid v. Kodak case for several years and have been unable to find any substantiation to this claim. I've also read in some cases the same plants were producing both Polaroid and Kodak film. So I'm not sure what's really going on.

My colleague also told me that during discovery a memo from Kodak was found which stated that Kodak knew that it was in violation of the Polaroid patents, but that Polaroid would probably never sue because of the expense. Likewise, I've been unable to find reporting of this memo. You would think that it would be in the court record, but I haven't been able to find it (and I assume it's huge).

So I'm looking for an answer to this question --- Did Polaroid's patents on integral photography describe a different technology than what Polaroid used? I don't know how to even research this question, other than lots of Google searches...

Comment: It’s unlikely that Polaroid’s commercial products were protected by trade secret. Anyone could just buy some film and reverse engineer the chemistry. In any case, this question is better directed to the Ask Patents SE site.

Comment: Thanks. I'll transfer to Ask Patents. However, @EricShain, your statement that "anyone would just buy some film and reverse engineering the chemistry" is incorrect.

Comment: In what way is it wrong. Trade secret provides no protection at all to reverse engineering.

Comment: Reverse engineering isn't nearly that good now, and certainly wasn't that good in the 1970s. Even knowing the chemicals doesn't tell you the process for making them or assembling the package. There are multiple thin film coatings on the inside of the integral film. Have you ever tried to reverse engineer a chemistry package?

Comment: @vy32: sorry for the slow response to your flag. Unfortunately the window for moving this question has now passed - if you do want to ask it on Ask Patents, just repost it there and then delete this one.